# how to install a package from github?

Tags: r

I need to install a github package
This is my code:

```
devtools :: install_github ("jgalgarra / kcorebip")
```

I already have the devtool installed but it gives me the following error:
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds
This is what I have configured in my Rprofile.site:

```
# Things you might want to change

# options (papersize = "a4")
# options (editor = "notepad")
# options (pager = "internal")

# set the default help type
# options (help_type = "text")
  options (help_type = "html")

# set a site library
# .Library.site <- file.path (chartr ("\\", "/", R.home ()), "site-library")

# set a CRAN mirror
# local ({r <- getOption ("repos")
# r ["CRAN"] <- "http: //my.local.cran"
# r ["CRAN"] <- http://cran.us.r-project.org
#options (repos = r)})

local ({r <- getOption ("repos")
       r ["Nexus"] <- "http://nexus.uo.edu.cu:8081/repository/R-repository/"
       options (repos = r)

})


# Give a fortune cookie, but only to interactive sessions
# (This would need the fortunes package to be installed.)
# if (interactive ())
# fortunes :: fortune ()
```

Can I modify any line to install the github or is it another problem?

Comment: Try removing the spaces on `install_github()`

Comment: `devtools::install_github("jgalgarra/kcorebip")`

Comment: also devtools 'uncoupled' so a more recent package to download from github would be using the `remotes` package.

Comment: It's not because of space still giving the same error

Comment: Have you taken the spaces out of the what's inside the install_github command, not just before it? With the spaces I get the same error as you and without (`devtools::install_github("jgalgarra/kcorebip")`) it works correctly.

Comment: try this after `install.packages("remotes")` , `remotes::install_github("jgalgarra/kcorebip")`

Comment: Without the spaces it does not work I get the following error: Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub: Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Comment: Please i need help!!